# Por que strcpy() é insegura?

Tags: c, string, segurança, memória

Eu estou lendo sobre programação segura, e li que a função `strcpy()`, da linguagem C, é um exemplo de função **insegura**.

Li também que há uma versão segura desta função, que seria a `strcpy_s()`.

Qual é a diferença funcional entre elas? Tem alguma relação com acessar posições de memória indevidas? Eu gostaria de um exemplo para entender a "insegurança" de `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro é importante dizer que é possível usar esta função de forma segura. O problema dela é que o programador pode se esquecer ou não saber como fazer isto.

O primeiro problema da função é que ela não considera o tamanho do que está copiando, então é possível sobrescrever uma área da memória que não era intencionado. Normalmente se aloca a memória onde a cópia da *string* será colocada e depois se faz a operação. Se o que for passado para esta função for maior que o espaço reservado, ela vai colocando dados além do espaço reservado. E esta é uma das formas de injetar um código malicioso em uma aplicação que se quer comprometer.

Outro problema é que ela não garante que o destino será terminado por um valor nulo `\0`, que é o que determina o fim de uma *string*, então outra parte do código pode ler esta memória esperando este caractere para saber quando parar de ler e não encontrará. Este problema também existe na `strncpy()`.

A função [`strcpy_s()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) (só disponível em C11) exige que se passe o tamanho do que será copiado e a função respeitará isto. Claro que se o programador não colocar um valor adequado (provavelmente igual ao que foi alocado) ela também será insegura. Ela garante que ao final tenha um nulo terminando a *string* adequadamente.

Se não tiver um compilador C11, pode usar [`strlcpy()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strlcpy&sektion=3), se disponível, ou [`strncpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/), que ainda tem problemas, mas já é um pouco melhor. De qualquer forma o programador sempre pode verificar antes de usar a função se o tamanho do *source*  é adequado ao *target* e pode garantir que o nulo seja colocado no final. Todo programador C decente tem uma função própria para fazer isto por ele se o compilador que ele usa não provê uma função padrão.

```
char * txt = malloc(10);
strcpy(txt, "teste maior do que devia"); //aqui já era! Vai ocupar uma memória indevida
strcpy_s(txt, 10, "teste maior do que devia"); //aqui só vai usar "teste mai"
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/SafeCopy.c).

Comment: A última linha seria `strcpy_s`? Resulta em erro na compilação: `too many arguments to function ‘strcpy’`

Comment: Oops, corrigido.

Comment: Na prática, não consegui fazer este código funcionar, mas este sim:http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy. No entanto, tentei trocar o tamanho em `strcpy_s` e não deu diferença. Não consegui visualizar a `strcpy_s` sendo insegura. Você consegue exemplificar isto?

Comment: Mas ela não é insegura.

Comment: Mas você disse na resposta: "claro que se o programador não colocar um valor adequado (provavelmente igual ao que foi alocado) ela também será insegura." Porém não consegui testar essa situação. Aliás, tentei testando com `2 * tamanho` e ela pegou `tamanho`.

Comment: Eu não sei que você testou, então não posso falar sobre isto.

Comment: Ok, mas você consegue citar um exemplo de código onde `strcpy_s` é insegura? Esta afirmação - de que `strcpy_s` pode ser insegura - está na sua resposta.

Comment: Não tenho um compilador para testar. Qualquer coisa pode ser insegura se usar errado.