# Por que uma atribuição de string em C não funciona?

Tags: c, ponteiro, estrutura-de-dados

Estou tendo dificuldades ao atribuir um valor a uma variável do tipo `char` de um `struct` eu estou fazendo o seguinte

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Animal{
    char nome[5]; // indiquei que a variavel nome tem 5 caractes
    int idade;
}Cachorro;

int main(){
    Cachorro Dog;
    Dog.idade = 9;
    Dog.nome = "Salfr"; // tento atribuir "Salfr" a minha variavel
    printf("'%s' '%d'", Dog.nome, Dog.idade);
    return 0;
}
```

so que esta ocorrendo um erro de [Falha de segmentação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falha_de_segmenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o)
quando eu compilo aparece `test.c|11|warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast|`

e quando eu executo aparece `Segmentation Fault`

agora quando eu indico que minha variavel char nome e um ponteiro funciona normalmente segue abaixo

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Animal{
    char *nome;
    int idade;
}Cachorro;

int main(){
    Cachorro Dog;
    Dog.idade = 9;
    Dog.nome = "Salfr";
    printf("'%s' '%d'", Dog.nome, Dog.idade);
    return 0;
}
```

ao compilar e executar recebo o seguinte retorno

```
'Safari' '9'
```

o meu problema esta relacionado com o tipo char referente a esta minha pergunta [Existe algum problema em atribuir um valor a um ponteiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136535/existe-algum-problema-em-atribuir-um-valor-a-um-ponteiro) eu sei que esse metodo nao e aconselhavel mas foi o unico modo que funcionou ate o momento alguem sabe por que esta acontecendo `Segmentation Fault` no primeiro exemplo?

Comment: use a função [strcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) para copiar o conteúdo da string para a sua variável `nome`.

Comment: Nos links a seguir você encontra perguntas e respostas que apesar de não serem as mesmas que você possuí podem lhe auxiliar a descobrir o motivo de seu código se comportar mal. Link 1 - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130792/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-array-de-char-e-ponteiro-de-char , Link 2 - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116333/ponteiro-de-char-ou-array-de-char .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O principal erro é achar que o operador de atribuição funciona para *strings*. Não dá, precisa chamar a função que copia os caracteres para onde deseja ([`strcpy()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126164/101)).

Ainda há o problema de faltar um byte para o caractere terminador `\0`. Toda *string* em C precisa de um byte a mais. C é uma linguagem bruta, o programador tem que se preocupar com tudo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
typedef struct Animal {
    char nome[6]; //o tamanho tem que ser 6 para acomodar o terminador
    int idade;
} Cachorro;
 
int main() {
    Cachorro dog;
    dog.idade = 9;
    strcpy(dog.nome, "Salfr"); //é a forma correta pra copiar uma string para uma variável
    printf("'%s' '%d'", dog.nome, dog.idade);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/K7ECL8). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/iyvrfenm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/StrCpy.c).

A versão com ponteiro funciona, desde que não deseje mexer no texto nunca. Ela está fazendo a estrutura apontar para um região da memória "pertencente ao código" e é protegida. O normal não é fazer isto. Isso pode ter funcionando por coincidência. Aí ela é uma solução pior porque não aloca memória necessária para sustentar o objeto texto. O texto só poderia ser manipulado após essa alocação. Mesmo que o fizesse ainda teria o problema da cópia que não está sendo feita.

Fiz alterações cosméticas, mas importantes. Fique atento.

Funcionar é uma coisa, estar certo é outra. Aconselho aprender o certo e não confiar no que funcionou. Pode ter sido só coincidência.

Comment: fogo e que eu encontrei varios exemplos na internet usando ponteiros voce poderia me indicar algum livro bom de c? @bigown

Comment: A maioria do material na internet sobre programação é muito ruim. Veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info. Mas vai perguntando, ou [pesquisando aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c?sort=votes&pageSize=50), tem muita coisa legal e avaliada por outras pessoas.

Comment: Correção: não há nenhum problema apontar para uma string literal,  espaço já é reservado pelo compilador e a string irá para a região de memória junto com constantes, o único problema é que você não poderá alterar a string, mas apontar para lá e ler o conteúdo, sem problemas.

Comment: @MurilloHenrique é verdade, é que considerei que em geral não é o que a pessoa deseja em código normal.

Comment: @bigown Com certeza, ainda mais se mais para frente, em um código extenso, houver erro por escrita no conteúdo de um ponteiro, rastrear isso seria muito complicado.