# Por que não e possível atribuir a um vetor de string depois de declarado, um caractere?

Tags: c, array

```
char vetor[10];
vetor = 10 /*ERROR*/
```

Por que acontece isso? Tem a ver com vetores serem compostos?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 4):

É possível, mas não faz o que deseja. O erro aí é que acessa uma área da memória que não devia. Um *array* é acessado sempre através de um endereço. O valor da variável é esse endereço. Quando tentar jogar 10 na variável está dizendo que o *array* inicia no endereço 10 da memória, que certamente é um local que você não pode acessar, aí dá problema mesmo.

Se quer colocar um valor no vetor tem que acessar o elemento, algo assim:

```
vetor[0] = 'A';
vetor[1] = 65;
*vetor = 'A';
*(vetor + 1) = 'A';
```

E se deseja jogar uma *string* toda para ele precisa fazer elemento por elemento, ou uma *string*, caractere por caractere. geralmente usa-se a [`strcpy()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136628/101).

Note que a aritmética de ponteiro considera o tamanho to tipo que o ponteiro aponta, ele tem uma multiplicação implícita pelo `sizeof(tipo apontado)`. Se tivesse que ser explícito escreveria assim:

```
*(vetor + (1 * sizeof(char))) = 'A';
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Assignment.c).

No caso de `char` sempre é 1, e nem precisaria, mas se fosse um `int`, poderia ser 2, ou 4 ( o mais comum), ou mais.

Comment: E qual o motivo de dizerem que vetor e um tipo composto?

Comment: Porque ele é composto por vários elementos, não é um só. Depois eu dou uma melhorada na resposta, ando com afazeres esses dias. Me cobre depois do carnaval se eu esquecer.

Answer (score 4):

Fazer a atribuição desse jeito não é possível simplesmente porque em C e C++ **o nome do array é um ponteiro para o início dele na memória**.

Para esclarecer essa questão, as instruções abaixo realizam exatamente a mesma tarefa: imprimir o endereço do início do array na tela (em hexadecimal):

```
printf("0x%x\n", vetor);
printf("0x%x\n", &vetor);
printf("0x%x\n", &vetor[0]);
```

**Saída:**

```
0xdbeedb00
0xdbeedb00
0xdbeedb00
```

Como é possível observar, essas instruções são equivalentes. É importante ressaltar que no seu computador, o endereço inicial do array (muito) provavelmente não vai ser este, mas qualquer que seja ele, as instruções irão imprimir o mesmo resultado.

Muito bem! Sabendo que o array começa neste endereço e também sabendo que o array tem 10 elementos do tipo `char`, é fácil descobrir aonde cada elemento do array vai ser armazenado na memória do computador:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("0x%x\n", &vetor[i]);
```

**Saída:**

```
0xdbeedb00
0xdbeedb01
0xdbeedb02
0xdbeedb03
0xdbeedb04
0xdbeedb05
0xdbeedb06
0xdbeedb07
0xdbeedb08
0xdbeedb09
```

Deste modo, a instrução `vetor = 10;` acaba sobrescrevendo o endereço do início do array, o que é um problema gravíssimo. Posteriormente, ao utilizar o array, o programa acabará acessando partes da memória que ele não tem direito de usar.

Lembre-se que quando quiser armazenar valores dentro do array é necessário usar os colchetes `[]` para indicar a posição dentro do array que irá guardar um novo valor:

```
vetor[0] = 10;
vetor[9] = 100;
vetor[5] = 60;
vetor[1] = 20;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Um vetor em C de declara desse jeito:

```
tipo vetor[TAMANHO];
```

o **TIPO** seria o tipo de variável que será aquele vetor como inteiro, char, etc.
lembrando que **String** nao existe no **C**, oque existe é o estilo **char**
Se você quer declarar um array do estilo string você terá que atribuir cada posição do vetor a somente 1 caractere daquele string que seria assim:

```
vetor[0] = 'T';
vetor[1] = 'E';
vetor[2] = 'S';
vetor[3] = 'T';
vetor[4] = 'E';
```

ao printar o vetor como todo ira aparecer o texto **TESTE** na saida do seu programa.

Comment: Defina *printar*.

Comment: Mostrar na tela do output do programa o famoso "prinf("olá Mundo");" da linguagem C

Comment: Então isso não produzirá o resultado esperado.

Comment: eu sei, eu somente comentei como que funciona mas ou menos o vetor, atribuindo caractere por caractere  e dps quando se printa ele mostra a string como toda no output