# Como obter o mesmo resultado de strcpy() com strcpy_s()?

Tags: c, c++, string, segurança, memória

Baixei um código em C++ da internet e quando abro a solução, da o seguinte erro:

> Erro  C4996   'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider
>   using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
>   _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

Seguindo a instrução, modifiquei o `strcpy` por `strcpy_s`. Porem gerou outros 2 erros:

> Erro  C2660   'strcpy_s': função não recebe 2 argumentos.
>
> Erro (ativo)  E0304   nenhum instância de função sobrecarregada
>   "strcpy_s" corresponde à lista de argumentos.

Por que ocorreu o primeiro erro? O que estou fazendo de errado?

Código:

```
strcpy((char*)m_pOriginalCVar->pszName, m_szDummyName);
```

Comment: Qual é o tipo de `m_szDummyName`?

Comment: @bfavaretto `char[128]`

Comment: Como o bigown disse `strcpy` é passivel de ataques de bufferoverflow e por isso criaram o `strcpy_s` que copia só um tamanho especifico de carateres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria algo assim:

```
strcpy_s((char*)m_pOriginalCVar->pszName, /*tamanho aqui*/, m_szDummyName);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/StrCpy_s.c).

Esse tamanho deve ser o tamanho de `(char*)m_pOriginalCVar->pszName` ou o tamanho de `m_szDummyName`, normalmente o que for menor e que fizer mais sentido, se for maior a função não faz milagre e erro do programador na boa escolha trará as mesmas consequências da função insegura.

Pode ser que tenha outras coisas a observar para garantir que a função consiga realizar a cópia segura, a função não fará nada inseguro, e o programador deve garantir que tudo esteja em ordem. A pergunta não tem detalhes que possam ajudar.

O erro ocorreu porque [`strcpy()` é insegura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126164/101).

[Documentação](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy). E na [documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=msvc-160).

Comment: Desculpe, eu escrevi errado, na verdade eu queria dizer com `_s`, creio que deveria ser: `strcpy_S((char*)m_pOriginalCVar->pszName, /*tamanho aqui*/, m_szDummyName);`

Comment: Sim, estava errado, acho que agora ok :)